# Characteristics Method PDE - Solution Verification

Tags: partial-differential-equations, solution-verification, characteristics, linear-pde

> $$\begin{cases}-x\partial_xu +y\partial_yu =-x^2u \\ u(x,1) = e^{-x} \end{cases}$$

I recently ask a question on PDE and I hope I understand how it works. Let $z(t)=u(x(t),y(t))$
$$\begin{cases}\dot{x}=-x\\ \dot{y}=y\\ \dot{z}=-x^2z \end{cases}$$
I think I can solve either for $t$ or using the first two row eliminating the time dependence and so I get with $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R}$
$$x(t)=\alpha e^{-t}\\ y(t)=\beta e^t$$
And without the time dependence - that is also the result I get from $\frac{dx}{-x}=\frac{dy}{y}$ -
$$xy=c_1\;, c_1\in \mathbb{R}$$
From the last row solving in x let $c_2 \in \mathbb{R}$
$$z=c_2\exp\bigg({-\frac{x^3}{3}}\bigg)$$
Since $c_2 = F(c_1)$
$$z=F(xy)\exp\bigg({-\frac{x^3}{3}}\bigg)\\u(1,x)=e^{-x}=F(x)\exp\bigg({-\frac{x^3}{3}}\bigg)\\ F(x) = \exp\bigg({\frac{x^3}{3}}-x\bigg) $$
And the general solution is
$$u(x,y) =  \exp\bigg({\frac{(xy)^3-x^3}{3}}-xy\bigg)$$
I think this solution has sense beacause plotting $u(x,y)$ and the parametric curve $\gamma(t)=(t, \frac{1}{t}, \exp\bigg(\frac{-t^3}{3}-\frac{2}{3}\bigg))$ I get
[image]

And the red line follows the surface, I don't know if this count as a solution verification. Any clarification, correction, signaling of unclear passages is welcome thank you very much

Comment: @Gonçalo ya I was overcomplicating solution check, I think I've done something wrong because putting the function I've found give me the false equation $x^3u=-x^2u$ :/

Comment: @Gonçalo I could not solve for x eliminating the time dependence?

Comment: I don't agree with your solution. You should check in putting the solution into the PDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$-x\partial_xu +y\partial_yu =-x^2u$$
Charpit-Lagrange characteristic ODEs :
$$\frac{dx}{-x}=\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{du}{-x^2u}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{-x}=\frac{dy}{y}$
$$xy=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving
$\frac{dx}{-x}=\frac{du}{-x^2u}$
$$e^{-x^2/2}u=c_2$$
This doesn't agree with your result.

General solution of the PDE on implicite form $c_2=F(c_1)$ :
$$e^{-x^2/2}u=F(xy)$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function (to be determined according to the boundary condition).
$$\boxed{u(x,y)=e^{x^2/2}F(xy)}$$

Condition :

$u(x,1)=e^{-x}=e^{x^2/2}F(x)$
$$F(x)=e^{-x-\frac12 x^2}$$
The function $F$ is determined. We put it into the above general solution where the argument is $xy$ thus $F(xy)=e^{-xy-\frac12 (xy)^2}$:

$u(x,y)=e^{x^2/2}e^{-xy-\frac12 (xy)^2}$
$$u(x,y)=e^{-xy-\frac12 (xy)^2+\frac12 x^2}$$
This is the particular solution which satisfies both the PDE and the condition.

NOTE :

Your parametrization with $t$ is equivalent to
$$\frac{dx}{-x}=\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{dz}{-x^2z}=dt \quad\implies\quad 
\begin{cases}
\frac{dx}{dt}=-x \\
\frac{dy}{dt}=y \\
\frac{dz}{dt}=-x^2z
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thank you I was recklessly integrating in $x$ when derivatives where in term of $t$. I haven't checked yet but, correct me if I'm wrong, replacing $x=ce^{-t}$ and integrating in $t$ in the last row should give me the same result. Now I get it's a waste of time because I want my result to be $x,y$ related but I'm just asking to see if I understand.

Comment: @Turquoise Tilt : Your mistake is in integrating $ \dot{z}=-x^2z$. In fact this is $\frac{dz}{dt}=-x^2z$ thus $\frac{dz}{z}=-x^2dt$. You integrate as it was $\frac{dz}{z}=-x^2dx$ which is not the same. To integrate you have to replace $x$ by $\alpha e^{-t}$.